# Remove black border from TcolorButton

Tags: delphi, button, firemonkey, delphi-xe5

Is there anyway to remove the black border from a TColorbutton ? Delphi xe5, developing for iOSdelp

Comment: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/FireMonkey_Style_Designer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are actually three black or gray borders.

First, add a custom stylebook to your app.  The docwiki tells how to do this:
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Customizing_the_Design_of_a_FireMonkey_Application

Follow step #2 (Step 3 doesn't work for mobile applications.)

Open the style editor and locate ColorButtonStyle.

Expand the tree node and click on "background" in the structure.

In the object inspector locate Fill and expand that node.

Change the fill Kind to bkNone.

That removes the wide gray bordered, leaving two dark gray 1px borders.

Further down the list of properties just below Sides is Stroke.

Change it's Kind to bkNone.  That removes the outer gray line.

Depending on your app you may need to also edit the color animations below the background rectangle. I did this by erasing (blanking out) the triggers since I was unable to delete the animations.

Next go the Fill component and set the stroke kind to bkNone.  That removes the inner gray line.

You may also also want to set the Fill Margins to 0 so the color extends to the outside of the object.  (i.e no padding now that the gray is not there.)

Gary